# method to create multiple UI labels in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

i have three objects, a UI label, a UI textfield and a UI button, i want to write a code that puts whatever is typed into the text field in the label and also make it draggable using a pan gesture, also i want to create a method thats makes this possible in the sense that a user can drag the label to any point on the screen and when the user types another text in the text field, it creates a new label with the text leaving the previous label on the screen.. i just want it to simply create draggable labels everytime i click the screen

```
- (void)change:(id)sender {

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init ];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = 
      [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self 
                                             action:@selector(panDetected:)];
    _label.text = _textField.text;
   [self.view addSubview:label];
   [label addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

i tried using this code but it doesnt create a new label instead it takes the previous label back to its original point and changes the text

Comment: Change `_label.text` to `label.text`.  Also, you need to set a `frame` for the new labels.

Comment: Xcode 4.6.2 wont let me use label, it says there is an error, also how do i create a frame for the labels?

Comment: What is the error?  `_label` and `label` aren't the same object.  You are basically creating blank labels and adding them to your view right now.  Here's more info on making UILabels: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7428554/1445366

Comment: it says they are the same object but use of undeclared identifier, so it suggests it with the underscore.. the first label works fine but i want to create new labels everytime i click on the button and changes the text and all the labels should be draggable but it works only for the first label..i want all draggable labels created to still be on the screen

Comment: this is the code from the .h file
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

-(IBAction)change:(id)sender;

Comment: Right, `_label` (aka `self.label`) is *one* UILabel.  All of your *other* UILabels are called `label` in the scope of that instance method.  You're probably synthesizing it to be called "label".  Try renaming your new labels to be called `myNewLabel` or something.